# errno 14 could not open/read file ///repodata/repomd.xml

Tags: linux, git, yum, xml, rhel-6

I have a Yum repository configured on my RHEL 6.4. By using the RHEL Custom Repository. I've registered another computer with that repository, but the installation of packages on that computer have failed.
following is the error that I'm facing.

```
file:///Repo/Packages/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///Repo/Packages/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: testrt. Please verify its path and try again
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure **repomd.xml** exists in that location ? Did you run **createrepo** ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on RHEL 6.7. The problem was that there was a local DVD repo pointing to /mnt/ where I don't really want it to check, since I wanted it to perform the lookup on remote repos.

I fixed it following the steps bellow:

- cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
- grep /Repo/Packages * -n
- disable the repos retrieved by the previous grep command (edit them with vi or your preferred text editor and set enabled=0)
- try to run your command again

Hope it helps,

Regards